# Triangle inequality for an obtuse triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, euclidean-geometry

[image]

$\alpha < 45^\circ$, how to show that

1) $|AB+AC|>|DB+DC|$?

2) $|AB+AC|>|DB+DC+DA|$?

Comment: @coffeemath any idea

Comment: Norman: See answer below. I only tackled inequality 1), and my method did not use $\alpha<45$, so I wonder if you know of a case where 1) fails for larger $\alpha$.

Comment: Norman: I've added a counterexample to the inequality labeled 2) in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1), note that the point $A$ is on an ellipse with foci at $B,C$ with length sum $|AB|+|BC|.$ The equality of the two marked angles $\alpha$ means that the ray $\vec{AD}$ is perpendicular to the ellipse at $A$, pointing into the ellipse. If as suggested by the diagram the point $D$ is in fact interior to the triangle $ABC$, then it follows that $D$ is interior to the ellipse, so that the length sum $|DB|+|DC|<|AB|+|BC|.$

Note that this argument didn't use $\alpha <45^{\circ}.$ Do you know of a case where inequality 1) fails when $\alpha$ is more than 45 degrees?

I haven't come up with anything (yet) on inequality (2).

NOTE on further looking at it, you don't need equality of the angles marked $\alpha$ in the diagram, or any inequality on the two angles there. All you need is that the point $D$ is interior to the triangle $ABC$, which the diagram clearly intends. Given any ellipse with foci at $B,C$, and any point $P$ on that ellipse, the triangle $BCP$ lies entirely in the interior of the ellipse, except for the point $P$ itself. It follows that any point $Q$ interior to triangle $BCP$ (so other than $P$) will have smaller length sum to the foci $B,C$ than does the point $P$ on the ellipse.

**Inequality 2) counterexample:**

Let $A=(0,0),B=(-1,9/10),C=(1,9/10),D=(0,8/10).$

Then $\alpha=\arctan(9/10) \approx 41.98^\circ,$ so that fits, and it's easy to see that $D$ is interior to triangle $ABC$. But computing AB+AC gives $\sqrt{181}/5 \approx 2.69072$, while computing the right side $DB+DC+DA$ gives $1/8+\sqrt{101}/5 \approx 2.80998,$ so that in this example the inequality stated in the OP as 2) turns out to have the right side greater than the left. There are also cases where the inequality *does* hold, e.g. if $D$ above is replaced by $(0,1/2)$. This shows there isn't an inequality either way between these two quantities, under the given assumptions.